# Opera natively plays WMV files?

Tags: asp.net, html5-video, opera, ashx, wmv

I was working on playing videos in HTML5 and displaying other content instead if the browser cannot play the video. I was looking at the results in Opera, and it played a WMV! I was really surprised. My installation of Opera is a fresh install with no extensions. It doesn't play if I try it the normal way, but when using an `ashx` handler and sending the content as MP4, it works!

*It does not work if I change it to the correct MIME type for WMV files.*

VideoHandler.ashx

```vb
' load file above and get bytes (the file is a WMV)
Dim bytes As Byte() = file.FileBytes
context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4" ' yes, I send it as an MP4
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

HTML5 (my content is added dynamically using ASP.NET, but I'll simplify it here)

```html
<video id="video" src="~/VideoHandler.ashx?&filesource=somesource&token=123456789" controls>
    Video preview not available
</video>
```

My question is essentially, how is this working?

I couldn't find any articles by searching that would indicate that Opera can play a WMV. This method doesn't play the WMV in Chrome, Firefox, or IE11.

*Note: I know that my "Video preview not available" content doesn't actually display on browsers that can't play the video, but this is unrelated to my question.*